# Correct umask value to automate the creation of file with the SSH private key content

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, permissions, umask

I'm trying to find a way to shorten these lines (`CI_PRIVATE_SSH_KEY` is already set):

```bsh
mkdir -p "${HOME}/.ssh/"
chmod 700 "${HOME}/.ssh/"
echo "${CI_PRIVATE_SSH_KEY}" > "${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa"
chmod 600 "${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

This is what I have so far:

```bsh
(umask 077; mkdir -p "${HOME}/.ssh/"; echo "${CI_PRIVATE_SSH_KEY}" > "${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa")
```

But this doens't quite work, because the directory is getting created with no `group` + `other` permissions.

So my question is: is there a `umask` value that let me create directories with `700` and files with `600` (provided the default value is `0022`)?

> I've also tried `177`, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to shorten the commands? Specifying the permissions makes it clear and obvious what your intentions are, versus relying on a umask.

Comment: Really not a big deal; I'm just trying to avoid longer debug streams because the CI process spits out some bits for every line that gets executed — I can't control that, it's set at the org level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i agreed with @Jeff Schaller,  chmod is clear and obvious versus umask.
try to build  one liner with `&&` operator
and the preferred permission of `.ssh` directory changed to 644
bash would try to run the command from left to right of the  `&&` operator
 and only continues when all the "left side" command return status is 0

```
mkdir -p "${HOME}/.ssh/" && chmod 644 "${HOME}/.ssh/" && echo "${CI_PRIVATE_SSH_KEY}" > "${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa" && chmod 600 "${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

or umask 133 for `.ssh` , 177 for the key,

```
(umask 133; mkdir -p "${HOME}/.ssh/";umask 177; echo "${CI_PRIVATE_SSH_KEY}" > "${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa")
```

Comment: OK, fair enough...good point. I can go with this one...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

umask 077 will:

- create directories with permission 700
- create files with permission 600

```bsh
    ➜ umask 077
    ➜ mkdir foo; ls -ld foo
    drwx------  2 richard  staff  64 13 Oct 12:42 foo
    ➜ touch foo/bar; ls -l foo/bar
    -rw-------  1 richard  staff  0 13 Oct 12:42 foo/bar
```